# How to apply RowScope and ColumnScope to the same content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to apply Row or Column depending on the orientation of the screen. To do this, I apply the following function:

```
@Composable
fun ComponentsPage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable (modifier: Modifier) -> Unit,
) {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

    when (configuration.orientation) {
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> { // horizontal
            Row(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                content(Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxHeight())
            }
        }
        else -> { // vertical
            Column(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                content(Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxWidth())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that internal variables such as `var enteredPassword by remember { mutableStateOf("") }` will be destroyed as we moved from one block to another on configuration change. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can do it with rememberSaveable as Sevban posted. This question was not about but using RowScope or ColumnScope, it's about retaining value on rotation change. Other option is to save your value inside a ViewModel or another presentation class that can survive configuration changes as ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rememberSaveable api instead of just remember.

```kotlin
   var text by rememberSaveable {
      mutableStateOf("")
   }

   TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
```

this way you won't lose your states across configuration changes like screen rotation.

Comment: I thought I'd tried that... But it works, thanks!